# .NET Entity Framework How to select records updated in the last 1 minute?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

The purpose of my application is to retrieve records based on a criteria.

The problem is that there could be millions of records but I only want to select records that were updated in the last 1 minute.

First time I select all records but after a minute I cannot select everything again as it would take a very long time. I only want to select Orders that were updated within that interval.

```
var records = context.Orders.Where(x => x.Category == "GAMING");
```

Is there something I could do? Subscribe to some sort of database event?

Comment: do you have an "updated at" column?

Comment: @DanielA.White No, I do not.

Comment: if it is a traditional rdbms, add a timestamp column to that Order table, create an index over it, and simply select where timestamp>=now()-1minute

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I see. I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with the word `timestamp` if working with Sql Server, there is a timestamp type but it has nothing to do with time. They renamed it to `rowversion` in later versions but the timestamp keyword is left in for backward compatability.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this would be by including a datetime column that held a timestamp (ex.DateInserted), and filtering based on its value:

```
var minuteAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);
var recordsThisMinute =  context.Orders.Where(x => x.DateInserted >= minuteAgo && x.Category == "GAMING");
```

However, if you wish to produce the same results, without touching the table you could always try the following:

```
//Assuming oldRecords is the variable in which
//you're storing the records you selected a minute ago
var recordsThisMinute = context.Orders.Where(x => x.Category == "GAMING").Except(oldRecords);
```

Comment: Be careful with the word `timestamp` if working with Sql Server, there is a timestamp type but it has nothing to do with time. They renamed it to `rowversion` in later versions but the timestamp keyword is left in for backward compatability. I would change the wording of your first sentence to *"The most efficient way to do this would be by including a datetime column that held a timestamp"*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use a static Dictionnary of idOrder,datetime in your DbContext managed in an overload off the SaveChanges method.

```
public static IEnumarable<Order> GetLastUpdatedOrder()
{
//Return dictionnay here
}
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var updatedOrder = ChangeTracker.Entries<Order>().Where(o => o.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
    //Manage here Your dictionnary
    var i = base.SaveChanges();
    return i;
}
```